# What 90s softcore sci-fi movie had two aliens crash-land on earth?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Can anyone help identify a film that would come on at night in the 90s? Two aliens (a guy and a girl) had become stranded/crashed/landed on earth and the movie is about them learning sexuality.

The girl had longish blonde hair. The guy had fairly long blonde hair too.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Something about this question screams "[USA Up All Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA_Up_All_Night)". Seriously though, I think there needs to be a little more information. Did they do anything except softcore sexual education?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Refer to [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/70236) on meta for list of possible details you can include in you question.

Comment: I am looking for the very same movie, hadn't found it yet. definitely not Escape from Galaxy 3. The requested movies was most probably produced end 80's or early 90's

Comment: the probably requested movie i saw between 1993-1995 and had impression it was new-ish at that time. blond hot girl, big musculous guy. Both are aliens, both look like human. Main characters however did not present themselves as royal. i remember only one scene. blue-ish scenery, something like an indoor lagoon with sprinkling water etc..

Answer (score 3):

I think this is [*Escape From Galaxy 3*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Galaxy_3) from 1981, also known as *Star Crash 2*.

Galactic immortals, a princess and her faithful Space Captain, are fleeing an evil conqueror. Landing on earth, they find out about love and sex, but lose immortality.

[image]

Comment: I see their "prop department" took their direction from Parliament Funakdelic.

Comment: You mean I could've been immortal if only I'd stayed a virgin forever?!  ... Eh, it was probably worth it.

Comment: STARCRASH 2: ESCAPE FROM GALAXY 3. Coming soon: ESCAPE FROM GALAXY 2: STARCRASH 3

Answer (score 2):

*Femalien 2* (1998)?

This was a softcore movie and involved two blonde alien characters studying human sexuality. Below is a story summary from IMDb.com:

> Two aliens come to Earth seeking their missing comrade, Kara, and find
>   that she has taken an intense interest in human sexual behavior. As
>   they follow along on her path, a nerdish UFO type and his fiance track
>   them, while a mysterious "man in black" tracks them. Written by

Here is the trailer from Dailymotion. Sorry, it looks choppy due to some bad editing.

https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=femalien+2+1998+movie&qpvt=femalien+2+1998+movie&view=detail&mid=06C3161F645F6E13D42806C3161F645F6E13D428&&FORM=VRDGAR

Comment: @Buzz - I've noticed that you're making lots of one- or two-character edits again. This tends to swamp the front page without adding much value to the questions and answers you're fixing.

Comment: @Valorum As always, I'm only editing things that are already on the front page.

Comment: @Buzz - Many of them are sufficiently borderline that I'm tempted (as I did last week when you went on your last mini-crusade) to roll some of them back. The general rule of thumb is that edits should be meaningful. Per the [FAQ]; "*Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged*"